# Shopify Cart Loop - Create variable for shipping time

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, shopify

I have the following conditional within the cart loop in my shopify cart page.

It creates a javascript variable which I use to display shipping time at the bottom of the page. I thought it was working but realised it only works for the last item in cart - duh.

So basically I need 'shippingtype' to be 'long' if ANY of the items are out of stock. I think there must be a simple way of doing this but I'm a peabrain :/

```
{% if item.quantity > item.variant.inventory_quantity %}
  <br><small style="color:orange">Some items made to order</small>
  <script>window.localStorage.setItem('shippingtype', 'long');</script>
{% else %}   
  <br><small style="color:green">Ready to dispatch</small>
  <script>window.localStorage.setItem('shippingtype', 'short');</script>
{% endif%}
```

Comment: Maybe I need to create an array, and check through for any 'long' values ?

Comment: I'm not following you completely but if you wan different shipping types, why don't yu include the `item.id` in the variable name so that you don't overwrite it? Example `shippingtype-{{item.id}}`. Or you can create an array as you mentioned an push each item in the array. I'm just not sure why you are using local storage if you don't plan to use this information on another page, but I don't know the whole picture here.

Comment: Ok thanks. To try an explain more...In stock items have short shipping time. Some items will have 0 stock and made to order, long shipping time. Some items have 3 stock but people might order 10 so 7 will be made to order. The final delivery date is dependent on what's in the cart , stock levels and order amounts. So the long/short shipping type varies on every customers checkout. That's why I'm using JavaScript variable though it may not need to be local storage...

Comment: To try to be clearer - shippingtype not meant to be associated with each item, but the whole cart.